# Should I use a straight-through or cross-over for router to extender cabling?

Tags: router, ethernet, repeater

I'm trying to conncect a router to a repeater (extender) should I use a straight-through or cross-over for the ethernet?

Comment: We would need more information to answer this because the capabilites and configurations of these devices can vary. If I were in your shoes I would just try a straight-through cable and see if it comes up, if it doesn't I'd assume I need a crossover. I expect that a straight through will work because normally you can use a straight through between a router and a switch and a repeater is more likely like a switch.

Comment: Before the days of Auto MDI/MDI-X the general rule was that connecting like/similar devices needs a crossover cable (switch to switch, router to router, etc.) and connecting unlike/dissimilar devices needs a straight through cable (workstation to switch, switch to router).

Comment: I have not needed a crossover cable in years. Most all network devices are auto-sensing these days.

Answer (score 3):

You need a straight-through cable since repeaters act as 'switch'.

[image]

Reference:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/10000-series-routers/46792-ethbase.html

Comment: That's a great table. There has been a great increase in the number of auto MDI/MDI-X ports out in the world, so more and more frequently it doesn't matter.